# How to avoid Pylint warnings for constructor of inherited class in Python 3?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, constructor, pylint

In Python 3, I have the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

This yields the Pylint warning:

> - Old-style class defined. (old-style-class)
> - Use of super on an old style class (super-on-old-class)

In my understanding, in Python 3 there does not exist an old-style class anymore and this code is OK.

Even if I explicitly use new-style classes with this code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

I get Pylint warning because of the different syntax to call the parent constructor in Python 3:

> - Missing argument to super() (missing-super-argument)

So, how can I tell Pylint that I want to check Python 3 code to avoid these messages (without disabling the Pylint check)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in astroid, which wasn't considering all classes as new style w/ python 3 before https://bitbucket.org/logilab/astroid/commits/6869fb2acb9f58f0ba2197c6e9008989d85ca1ca

That should be released shortly.

Comment: Thanks! This just raises the additional question on how to tell Pylint, which Python version to use at its checks. I entered a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309636/check-python-3-source-with-pylint-running-with-python-2

Answer (score 5):

According to [this list](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages) 'Missing argument to super()' has code E1004: .If you want to disable only one type of warning you can add this line at the beginning of the file:

```
# pylint: disable=E1004
```

Or you can try calling `super()` like this:

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(B, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks, you may even disable the message by `# pylint: disable=missing-super-argument`. However, is there something wrong with my Python code or is Pylint not Python 3 compatible?

Comment: I am not sure as I am running on python 2.7. pylint version 1.1 should support python 3 as well.