# Check Python 3 source with Pylint running with Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pylint

Some checks of Pylint are depending on whether the checked source code is of kind Python 2 or Python 3. E.g., see [How to avoid Pylint warnings for constructor of inherited class in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235021/how-to-avoid-pylint-warnings-for-constructor-of-inherited-class-in-python-3).

In my setup I run Pylint on a development server, which is using Python 2.7. However, I use Pylint to automatically check Python 3 code on each commit.

How can I configure Pylint to perform checking for Python 3, even if it runs under Python 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Pylint is using the builtin Python parser, and also get standard library information on demand, so the Python version running Pylint has a high impact on its output.

You should have several Pylint installations if you want to use it to check both Python 2 and Python 3 code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pylint using pip3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pylint
```